# RWeka M5P model tree in Rmd chunk gives an error

Tags: r, rweka

I create a Model-tree with the following command:

```
Tree_Model <- RWeka::M5P(Formule_Train, data = AB_Train)
```

Then the following line executes fine inside a R-chunk in a Rmd-file:

```
Tree_Model_Test <- predict(Tree_Model, newdata=AB_Test)
```

But when I try to knit the document, I get this error:

```
Error in .jcall(o, "Ljava/lang/Class;", "getClass") : 
  RcallMethod: attempt to call a method of a NULL object.
Calls: <Anonymous> ... .predictions_for_instances -> .has_method -> .jcall
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After changing the line

```
Tree_Model <- RWeka::M5P(Formule_Train, data = AB_Train)
```

to

```
library(RWeka)
Tree_Model <- M5P(Formule_Train, data = AB_Train)
```

knitr didn't complain anymore

Ben

And 7 minutes later I got the same error as before :-(